# socket with external and internal ip address

Tags: c++, network-programming

i would like to know a text messenger apps likes whatsapp
i got some network problem for this

a chat program in PC :

server(1.2.3.5)
router A(1.2.3.4)
router B(1.2.3.6)

under router A there have 2 computer
A(192.168.0.2)
B(192.168.0.3)

under router B there have 2 computer
C(192.168.0.4)
D(192.168.0.5)

when D want to connect to A, it send the msg to server, and server forward the msg to A, and the router(1.2.3.4) need to set port forward rules
for example the chat program use port 999
when the server send a msg to 1.2.3.4:999 the router(1.2.3.4) forward the msg to A(192.168.0.2:999), it can be set router setting on PC

but when we are using a phone and connect to wifi
the external ip of phone is changed and assign an internal ip, but clearly we can't make a port forward rules on that router
than how can a text messenger(or whatsapp) work well with network?

Comment: Please capitalize and puntuate this incomprehensible question.

Answer (score 0):

The server needs to communicate with a machine that is on a different subnet. You have two choices:

- Have the client initiate the connection to the server. This is how Skype works, for example. Once the client is connected, the server can send data to it.
- Have the client forward a known port on the router using [uPnP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Plug_and_Play). This, however, requires that the server know the port and host in advance. Except for specific applications (such as BitTorrent), this is not usually possible.